# merge javascript code between upload display image with choose from modal box

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

need help. i struggling to merge display preview with choose image from modal box

here is the script
display preview code

```
<div id='div_img_name'></div>
    <?php if(!empty($data)) { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo base_url().'public/img/upload/coupons/'.$data["file_name"]?>" class="coupon_pic"/>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <img id="output_image" class="coupon_pic"/>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="coupon_btn">
      <div class="upload">
        <input type="file" id="upload_button_input"  onchange="preview_image(event)" name="file_name" style="display:none"  ></input>
        <button id="upload_button">アップロード</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="choose" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">選択</button>

 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">

     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Select Image</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <?php
         foreach ($galleries as $key => $value)
         { ?>
           <input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url().'public/img/upload/coupons/'.$value["file_name"]?>" name="gallery_id" value="<?php echo $value["id"]?>" height="100" width="130"  class="img">

         <?php } ?>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

function preview_image(event){
    $("#div_img_name").empty();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
        output.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
$(".img").click(function() {
      var img = $(this).attr('src');
      $("#div_img_name").empty();
      $('#div_img_name').prepend('<input type="image" alt="Login" src="' + img + '" class="coupon_pic" name="gallery_id" value="2"> ');
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      return false;
  });
```

when i want upload image. it display properly. but after that, i choose image from modal box. it preview double.

beside that. how do i get the value from input type="image" because the image from modal box contain ID.